# RecycleView not calling methods

Tags: android

I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON, but it doesn't seem to work. OnBindViewHolder is never called...

ADAPTER CODE:

```
public class AdapterRallye extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRallye.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    private List<DataRallye> data;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView Rallye_Nom;
        public ImageView Rallye_Foto;
        public TextView Rallye_Provincia;
        public TextView Rallye_DataI;
        public TextView Rallye_Tipus;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Rallye_Nom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nom);
            Rallye_Foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);
            Rallye_Provincia = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provincia);
            Rallye_DataI = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_datai);
            Rallye_Tipus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tipus);
        }
    }

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterRallye(List<DataRallye> dadesrally) {
        this.data = dadesrally;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.container_rallye, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);


        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        DataRallye current = data.get(position);
        holder.Rallye_Nom.setText(current.getRallyeNom());
        holder.Rallye_Tipus.setText(current.getRallyeTipus());
        holder.Rallye_DataI.setText(current.getRallyeDataI());
        holder.Rallye_Provincia.setText(current.getRallyeProvincia());
        holder.Rallye_Provincia.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load("http://rallyecat.esy.es/fotos/" + current.getRallyeFoto())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.rallyecatlogo)
                .error(R.drawable.rallyecatlogo)
                .into(holder.Rallye_Foto);

    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onClick(view);
    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


}
```

FRAGMENT CODE:

```
public class FragmentRally extends Fragment {
    public FragmentRally() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private List<DataRallye> llistarallyes = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdapterRallye mAdapter;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_rally, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.llistarallyes);

        mAdapter = new AdapterRallye(llistarallyes);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        new AsyncFetch().execute();

        mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitatDetalls.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombarra", llistarallyes.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getRallyeNom());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tCarregant...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json llistarallyes
                url = new URL("http://www.rallyecat.esy.es/Obtenir_events.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive llistarallyes from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve llistarallyes from json file
                //conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read llistarallyes sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    // Pass llistarallyes to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No hi ha connexió a internet.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return ("No hi ha connexió a internet.");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract llistarallyes from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataRallye dadesrallye = new DataRallye();
                    dadesrallye.setRallyeNom(json_data.getString("nom"));
                    dadesrallye.setRallyeTipus(json_data.getString("tipus"));
                    dadesrallye.setRallyeDataI(json_data.getString("datai"));
                    dadesrallye.setRallyeProvincia(json_data.getString("provincia"));
                    dadesrallye.setRallyeFoto(json_data.getString("foto"));
                    llistarallyes.add(dadesrallye);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_rally, parent, false));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivitatDetalls.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen other StackOverflow posts where the problem is already solved, but I've been trying alot of the solutions the user said, but none is working...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in onPostExecute() method.

You need to notify your adapter after you made changes.

Comment: That seemed to solve it half way, now it crashes, saying that context is null.

Comment: @FranB. put your error logs to your Question. This is a different error.

Comment: It was my fault, I was calling a null context, I deleted the code that I wasn't using, and it works now! So thank you!